# Strange behavior in long-running XML parsing method

Tags: android, performance, xml-parsing

We have the following method to parse an XML file and display its contents accordingly:

```
@Background
@AfterInject
void parseXMLAndLoadContent() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URI);
        xmlParser.setInput((InputStream) url.getContent());
        showProgressDialog();
        angeboteXML = xmlParser.parse();
        if (angeboteXML != null) {  // Breakpoint here              
            if (angeboteXML.backgroundImage != "") {
                loadBitmapFromUrl(angeboteXML.backgroundImage);
            }
            loadAngebote();
        } else
            throw new Exception();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        showToast();
    } finally {
        dismissProgressDialog();
    }
}
```

As you can see it is supposed to show the a progress dialog (method annotated with `@UiThread`), then call the XML parser and handle the result.

Unfortunately, this does only work when I set a breakpoint in the line mentioned above, just after the call of `parse()`. Somehow, this leads to a certain grace period, that allows the parser to handle the document. If I just let it run without the breakpoint, nothing happens, not even the progress dialogue shows up and `angeboteXML` is null.

Since I am no Android expert - why is this happening and is there anything I can improve? As far as my understanding goes, this should be executed sequentially, i.e. after the parser is done parsing, everything else is executed. But this is somehow not the case here.

**Edit 16/05/13 13:21:**

Adding a `Thread.sleep(1000)` after `parse()` helps, but it seems more like a workaround than a fix.

This is the trace log of method execution:

```
05-16 13:19:26.168: I/AngeboteActivity(6051): Entering [void parseXMLAndLoadContent() ]
05-16 13:19:26.278: I/AngeboteXMLParser(6051): Entering [public de.sample.app.helper.AngeboteXML parse() throws org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException, java.io.IOException] 
05-16 13:19:26.318: I/AngeboteXMLParser(6051): Exiting [public de.sample.app.helper.AngeboteXML parse() throws org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException, java.io.IOException], duration in ms: 35 
05-16 13:19:26.318: I/AngeboteActivity(6051): Exiting [void parseXMLAndLoadContent() ], duration in ms: 147 
05-16 13:19:26.318: I/AngeboteActivity(6051): Entering [void loadAngebote() ]
```

`loadAngebote()` is where a NPE is thrown, since the parser seems to be not yet finished.

**Edit 16/05/13 13:29**

This is how the `parse()` method is implemented:

```
public AngeboteXML parse() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {     
    this.xml = new AngeboteXML();

    int eventType = this.parser.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG :
                this.readStartTag(this.parser.getName());
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG :
                this.readEndTag(this.parser.getName());
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.TEXT :
                this.readText(this.parser.getText());
                break;
            default :
                break;
        }
        this.parser.next();
        eventType = this.parser.getEventType();
    }

    return xml;
}
```

Comment: Just figured out: adding a `Thread.sleep(1000)` after calling `parse()` helps. Still don't understand this.

Comment: Which XML parser implementation are you using?

Comment: `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser`

Comment: @SebastianWramba I don't see a parse() method in the documentation.

Comment: @Logician Added its implementation to the question

Comment: @SebastianWramba I see. It looks correct, according to the documentation. Try outputting the parsing result to LogCat, see if it misses anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think this is a design problem. The call to xmlParser.parse() is the task you want to execute in the background. Everything before and after that belongs in another method, which triggers this task.

I don't know how the @Background feature works, but if you would use the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html, there would be a onProgressUpdate (put showProgressDialog() in here) and a onPostExecute callback (put         dismissProgressDialog() in here). Looking at the documentation of android annotations, I would suggest the following:

```
@AfterViews
void initXMLParsing() {
    showProgressDialog();
    parseXMLAndLoadContent();       
}

@Background
void parseXMLAndLoadContent() {
    try {
        // ...
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        showToast();
    } finally {
        dismissProgressDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seemed strange to me as well. Doing it like this (which is actually a quite common pattern) helped.